# How to update folder properties in Jenkins folder?

Tags: jenkins

I am using the Folder Properties plugin with Jenkins.


I have created a property called FOO with a value of "yes" in a Jenkins folder.


Is there a REST command I can use to get and update the values of a folder property? 

Example:

Change the value FOO to "no".

Answer (score 1):

curl -u username:password -X GET https://jenkins-url.com/job/Folder1/config.xml -o folder.xml